# Getting error in asp.net mvc5 app when saving to database I think. The only message is Error. An error occurred while processing your request

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, sql-server-2014

I have an asp.net mvc5 application that I created about a year ago and it was working.  I did it in Visual Studio 2015 and then published it to a production server.  I just did an update to the application and republished it.  I now get an error when the application tries to save I think.  The error, " Error.  An error occurred while processing your request." does not tell much.  I turned off Customerrors in hopes of getting more information but I still get the same message.  Not sure how to find out why it is no longer able to save.  I have checked all the account permissions based on other site suggestions.  Is it possible some recent updates to Server 2012 or Sql Server 2014 require additional changes?  Any help on how to find the actual error message would help a lot.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of work on the Visual Studio I realized the VS2015 was very out of date.  I tried to run updates on it but it would not succeed.  That is why my apps would not update.  Visual Studio was the problem all along.  I finally moved to Visual Studio 2019 and then upgraded my applications from ASP.net mvc5 to ASP.net MVC Core.  I realize now it is important to update the Visual Studio on a frequent basis.  If you wait too long it may not allow for an update.